# Add entries to multidimensional list in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list, which composed of multiple list. How can I add `"newentry1"` and `"newentry2"` entries to all of those multiple entries? So, for all `my_list$Point` I should have `my_list$Point$myentry1` and `my_list$Point$myentry2`

```
my_list <- list(Point = list(position = "1", Production = "98.40", 
                  imbalance_Price.category = "A06"), Point = list(position = "2", 
                                                                  Production = "0.00", imbalance_Price.category = "A06"), 
     Point = list(position = "3", Production = "0.00", 
                  imbalance_Price.category = "A06"), Point = list(position = "4", 
                                                                  Production = "0.00", imbalance_Price.category = "A06"), 
     Point = list(position = "5", Production = "0.00", 
                  imbalance_Price.category = "A06"), Point = list(position = "6", 
                                                                  Production = "188.70", imbalance_Price.category = "A06"))
```

The final outcome should be:

```
my_list <- list(Point = list(position = "1", Production = "98.40", 
                             imbalance_Price.category = "A06",myentry1 = "A", myentry2 = "B"), Point = list(position = "2", 
                                                                             Production = "0.00", imbalance_Price.category = "A06",myentry1 = "A", myentry2 = "B"), 
                Point = list(position = "3", Production = "0.00", 
                             imbalance_Price.category = "A06",myentry1 = "A", myentry2 = "B"), Point = list(position = "4", 
                                                                             Production = "0.00", imbalance_Price.category = "A06",myentry1 = "A", myentry2 = "B"), 
                Point = list(position = "5", Production = "0.00", 
                             imbalance_Price.category = "A06",myentry1 = "A", myentry2 = "B"), Point = list(position = "6", 
                                                                             Production = "188.70", imbalance_Price.category = "A06",myentry1 = "A", myentry2 = "B"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
lapply(my_list, function(Point) {
  Point$myentry1 <- "A"
  Point$myentry2 <- "B"
  Point
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked out. but if i.e. I want to add multiple entries say myentry1<- "test1" and  myentry2<- "test2" to two different Point$entry1 and Point$entry2?

Comment: @PriitMets Glad that it helps. Could you edit your question to provide a complete example of the desired input and output?

Comment: Thank you but still incomplete. Could you provide the desired output in the same form you've provided `my_list`?

Comment: Added a list with the final outcome

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my answer accordingly. Though the question is still missing the input `myentries`, so I am making an assumption on its shape.

Comment: In the final list I added variables explicitly, the following logic myentry1<- 'A', myentry2 <- 'B'

Comment: Got it, I've edited my answer accordingly again.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::map`:

```r
library(purrr)

map(my_list, ~ append(.x, list(myentry1 = "A", myentry2 = "B")))

#> $Point
#> $Point$position
#> [1] "1"
#> 
#> $Point$Production
#> [1] "98.40"
#> 
#> $Point$imbalance_Price.category
#> [1] "A06"
#> 
#> $Point$myentry1
#> [1] "A"
#> 
#> $Point$myentry2
#> [1] "B"
#> 
#> 
#> $Point
#> $Point$position
#> [1] "2"
#> 
#> $Point$Production
#> [1] "0.00"
#> 
#> $Point$imbalance_Price.category
#> [1] "A06"
#> 
#> $Point$myentry1
#> [1] "A"
#> 
#> $Point$myentry2
#> [1] "B"
#> 
#> 
#> $Point
#> $Point$position
#> [1] "3"
#> 
#> $Point$Production
#> [1] "0.00"
#> 
#> $Point$imbalance_Price.category
#> [1] "A06"
#> 
#> $Point$myentry1
#> [1] "A"
#> 
#> $Point$myentry2
#> [1] "B"
#> 
#> 
#> $Point
#> $Point$position
#> [1] "4"
#> 
#> $Point$Production
#> [1] "0.00"
#> 
#> $Point$imbalance_Price.category
#> [1] "A06"
#> 
#> $Point$myentry1
#> [1] "A"
#> 
#> $Point$myentry2
#> [1] "B"
#> 
#> 
#> $Point
#> $Point$position
#> [1] "5"
#> 
#> $Point$Production
#> [1] "0.00"
#> 
#> $Point$imbalance_Price.category
#> [1] "A06"
#> 
#> $Point$myentry1
#> [1] "A"
#> 
#> $Point$myentry2
#> [1] "B"
#> 
#> 
#> $Point
#> $Point$position
#> [1] "6"
#> 
#> $Point$Production
#> [1] "188.70"
#> 
#> $Point$imbalance_Price.category
#> [1] "A06"
#> 
#> $Point$myentry1
#> [1] "A"
#> 
#> $Point$myentry2
#> [1] "B"
```